# open audio device in android dev/msm_pcm_out without it getting locked through native c code

Tags: android

I am trying to open dev/msm_pcm_out using native c code but the media player is giving out no sound , is it possible to open the device without locking it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permissions to access this device? Typically `msm_pcm_out` will be owned by the `system` process, and access to it will be restricted to the owner process and the group the owner belongs to.

A more important question is *why* are you trying to access this device? The `msm_pcm_out` device is only available on older Qualcomm platforms. Their never platforms do PCM output/input through the ALSA PCM devices in /dev/snd/, and platforms from other vendors obviously don't have the msm_-devices at all since they're a Qualcomm-thing.

Comment: currently the phone i am using has this device , by running your native service as a system service using adb shell you can have access to the device look at asl(android-screenshot-library)

Comment: or is there anyway i can capture the sound through the audio flinger ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Record all audio that's being played on the phone..? There's no way of doing that in Android, unless you're running a custom ROM where you've e.g. modified the AudioFlinger and/or AudioStreamOut code.

Comment: yeah ive been trying to record the audio of the phone and i have found no other way to do it except what you are suggesting since the audio device uses mutex and you cannot open the device when the audio is playing and if you open it the audio stops playing hence no way to record the audio unless i run a custom ROM as you have suggested Thank you !!